# JAVA- How to reinitialise the second statement in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, conditional-statements

My code takes the users input and checks it for certain characters. If a unwanted character is found the programme asks for user input again however if I were to type the special character at the end of the text eg 'hello@' and then when im asked for the input again I type 'hello' I get a 'String index out of range: 5' error. How could I reinitialize the max variable so that when the input length changes max variable in the for loop changes too.
I tried assigning the max variable again but there was no luck.

```
Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter text to encrypt:");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        String text = input.toUpperCase();
        char letter;
        int max = text.length();
        for(int i =0; i<max;i++){
           letter = text.charAt(i);
          while(letter=='@'||letter=='\''||letter==';'||letter==':'||letter==','||letter=='<'||letter=='.'||letter=='>'||letter=='/'||letter=='?'||letter=='#'||letter=='~'||letter=='['||letter==']'||letter=='{'||letter=='}'||letter=='='||letter=='+'||letter=='-'||letter=='_'||letter==')'||letter=='('||letter=='*'||letter=='&'||letter=='^'||letter=='%'||letter=='$'||letter=='$'||letter=='£'||letter=='"'||letter=='!'||letter=='`'||letter=='¬'||letter=='\\'||letter=='|'){
            System.out.println("Invalid Input\nPlease enter text to encrypt:");
            input = keyboard.nextLine();
            text = input.toUpperCase();
              letter = text.charAt(i);
              i=-1;
          }
          max=text.length();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take the user input and validate it. If the input is invalid, you request it again. One way of doing this is something like:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean ok;

do {

    ok = true;
    System.out.println( "Please enter text to encrypt:" );
    String text = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    
    for ( char letter : text.toCharArray() ) {
        if ( letter=='@' || letter=='\'' || letter==';' || letter==':' || 
             letter==',' || letter=='<' || letter=='.' || letter=='>' ||
             letter=='/' || letter=='?' || letter=='#' || letter=='~' || 
             letter=='[' || letter==']' || letter=='{' || letter=='}' || 
             letter=='=' || letter=='+' || letter=='-' || letter=='_' ||
             letter==')' || letter=='(' || letter=='*' || letter=='&' ||
             letter=='^' || letter=='%' || letter=='$' || letter=='$' ||
             letter=='£' || letter=='"' || letter=='!' || letter=='`' ||
             letter=='¬' || letter=='\\' || letter=='|' ) {
            ok = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if ( !ok ) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    }
    
} while ( !ok );
```

I'm assuming that you want a String with only alphanumerical characters. If it's true, it could be much simpler:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean ok;

do {

    System.out.println( "Please enter text to encrypt:" );
    String text = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    
    // does text contains only characters from A to Z and/or 0 to 9,
    // one or more times (+)
    ok = text.matches( "[A-Z0-9]+" );
    
    if ( !ok ) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    }
    
} while ( !ok );
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you just want legal `alphaNumeric` words.  `\\w+` matches those so try this.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true) {
    System.out.println("Please enter text to encrypt:");
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();
    if (input.matches("\\w+")) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
}
```